# Is there a second state for ctrl + c (x) / ctrl + v in VS code or any other IDE

Tags: visual-studio, performance, plugins, ide, copy-paste

I often find myself copy pasting 2 near exact parts of code/text or 2 interchanging copy paste items.

This got me wondering if there was a plugin or IDE that allows you to have 2 different 'copy' states?

For instance: `Ctrl + C` (copy 1) / `Ctrl + MB4 + C` (copy 2)
And of course also a second paste option so For instance: `Ctrl + V` (copy 1) / `Ctrl + MB4 + V` (copy 2)

Anyone that has experience with a plugin like this, I could not find anything like this in VS code?

*MB4 = Mouse button 4

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extensions in VS code that do this it seems, I was searching on the wrong keywords. Found them by searching for 'clipboard' in VS Code.